# Exclude field while reading in child entity using jpa oracle db

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I want to exclude some of the fields in child entity using jpa.
Ex :

```
Class Person extends Serializable
{
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String id;
     private PersonalInformation personalInformation;
}

Class PersonalInformation extends Serializable
{
     private Date dob;
     private List<PersonalDocument> documents; 
}

Class PersonalDocument extends Serializable
{
     private String fileName;
     private int fileSize;
     private byte[] fileData;
}
```

When I tried to get the details of a person, I could get all the information about a person, including PersonalInformation and PersonalDocument list, but since PersonalDocument.fileData can be huge, every time getting this field from DB is impacting the performance.

So I wanted to ignore/exclude PersonalDocument.fileData field while reading only, I wanted to know how to write the jpa query for the same.

Comment: Setting the FetchMode for the field, or using EntityGraphs allow you to do that

Answer (score 0):

One solution then would be to have the file data lazily fetched i.e. fetched on demand from the database when you access the field. Note that JPA specification does not require that provider implementations actually support the lazy loading of individual fields (rather than associations): any directives in this area can only be considered as a hint to the persistence provider.

I know that Hibernate does support the lazy loading of fields and there are lots of similar questions in this area but I have been unable to find a *definitive* answer about exactly what is required.

Firstly, however you need to mark the field with the @`Lob` annotation (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html)

```
import javax.persistence.Lob;

public class PersonalDocument implements Serializable
{
     private String fileName;
     private int fileSize;

     @Basic(fetch=LAZY) //optional??
     @Lob
     private byte[] fileData;
}
```

The following suggests that `@Lob` is lazy by default and so we may not need the additional `@Basic(fetch=LAZY)` however no harm in adding it anyway.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-418

While some similar Stack Overflow questions appear to report that adding `@Lob` is all that is required to have such fields lazily loaded,  the Hibernate docs themselves note that lazy field loading requires byte code enhancement.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

> To enable property level lazy fetching, your classes have to be
>   instrumented: bytecode is added to the original class to enable such
>   feature, please refer to the Hibernate reference documentation. If
>   your classes are not instrumented, property level lazy loading is
>   silently ignored.

So, in summary:

1. Add @Lob and see if it works.
2. If not, add @Basic(fetch=LAZY) and see if it works.
3. if not, either add byte code enhancement to your build.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/bytecode/BytecodeEnhancement.html